# Empty array() to be serialized as JSON object literal

Tags: php, json

I have the following code in `PHP`:

```
$response = array(
 "code"=>"100",
 "message"=>"Invalid input",
 "details"=>array(
 ));
echo json_encode($response);
```

That returns a `JSON` as follows:

```
{"code":"100","message":"Invalid input","details":[]}
```

How can I make the `PHP` script returns a `JSON` like that :

```
{"code":"100","message":"Invalid input","details":{}}
```

With `{}` instead of `[]`.

Comment: Why? json_encode is doing what it's supposed to do. details is an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to make the details key be an object, not an array.

```
<?php
$response = array(
"code"=>"100",
"message"=>"Invalid input",
"details"=>new StdClass()
);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Output: `{"code":"100","message":"Invalid input","details":{}}`

Comment: What? Why have you chosen this method while `json_encode` has an option for it?

Comment: Yeah, I would have gone with any other answer, I just didn't know they existed when I wrote mine.

Answer (score 6):

Though I do not agree, try:

```
echo json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can force empty array to be render as object [with the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option](http://www.php.net/json_encode):

```
echo json_encode(array(), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
// Returns {}
echo json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
// Returns {"code":"100","message":"Invalid input","details":{}}
```